# How can I make Terraform perform the virtual_machine_extension containing a sed command?

Tags: shell, sed, terraform

I want to disable the user password when a VM is creating using this command:

`sudo sed -i -E '/^username/s/^([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*)(:.*)$/\1:!!:'$(($(date +%s)/86400))':\4:99998\6/' /etc/shadow`

in Terraform virtual_machine_extension. I´ve tested the command on a freshly created VM and it works, but when using it with Terraform I get this Error:

```
Error: Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'vm-02'. Error message: \"Command returned an error.\n---stdout---\n\n---errout---\nsed: -e expression #1, char 71: unterminated `s' command\n\n\"."

  on ../modules/vm.tf line 100, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "disable_pw":
 100: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "disable_pw" {
```

I already tried to escape `\` with `\\`. Running this exact vm_extension with other bash commands works fine.

Did someone has experience in it?

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "disable_pw" {
  name                        = "${var.vm_hostname}
  location                    = "${module.global_variables.location}"
  resource_group_name         = "${module.global_variables.resource_group_name}"
  virtual_machine_name        = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux.name}"
  publisher                   = "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions"
  type                        = "CustomScriptForLinux"
  type_handler_version        = "1.5"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version  = false

  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "sudo sed -i -E '/^username/s/^([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*)(:.*)$/\1:!!:'$(($(date +%s)/86400))':\4:99998\6/' /etc/shadow"
    }
    SETTINGS

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {

    }
    SETTINGS

}
```

Comment: There is an extra **s** in the starting of your sed command `sed -i -E 's/`.
Remove it and give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will work**

```
sed  -E '/^username/s/^([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*)(:.*)$/1:!!:'$(($(date +%s)/86400))':4:999986/g' /etc/shadow
```

**Explanation:**

1. s/ is used after checking the required username.
2. use '\' escaping only for special characters like regex.

Comment: Thank you, but it still throws the same Error. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: What shell you are using for execution?